# ReactJS: How to return object asynchronously after fetching data in loop?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a react function as shown below:

```
const requestSideBarData = (state, request) => {

    let newState = state;
    Object.keys(newState.data).forEach(element => {
         axios.post(`${ApiEndPoints.getDropDownHeaders}${element}`,request)
        .then(response => {
            newState.data[element] = response.data;
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            
        });
    });
    return newState;

};
```

I want to return the newState after all the post response has been recieved and newState has been updated. How should I go about it? Since the function runs syncly it returns the same state without letting axios complete its response.

Comment: Read about promise and refactor your code

Comment: Try making requestSideBarData function async and await on Foreach loop. A promise can be a great alternative as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```js
const requestSideBarData = async(state, request) => {

    let newState = state;
    const promises = [];
    Object.keys(newState.data).forEach(element => {
        promises.push(axios.post(`${ApiEndPoints.getDropDownHeaders}${element}`,request))
    });
    const results = await Promise.all(promises);
    var index = 0;
    Object.keys(newState.data).forEach(element => {
        newState.data[element] = results[index++].data;
    })
    return newState;

};
```

Comment: i just updated the answer newly, try with the updated one.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
const requestSideBarData = async (state, request) => {
  let newState = state;
  for(let element in Object.keys(newState.data)) {
    try {
      let response = await 
        axios.post(`${ApiEndPoints.getDropDownHeaders}${element}`,request);
      newState.data[element] = response.data;
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
  return newState;
};
```

now that you've declared `requestSideBarData` body to be async, it will automatically return a promise, and you'll need to deal with it when calling the function.

I've also replaced `forEach` loop with `for...in` because `forEach` loop cannot run async by default. Now in every iteration loop will `await` the axios.post.

Ideally, you shouldnt `await` on every `async` function when you have a lot of them. see William Wang's answer to make all requests asynchronously and `await` on them all at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
const requestSideBarData = (state, request) => {
    let newState = state;
    try {    
        Object.keys(newState.data).forEach(async (element) => {
        const url =`${ApiEndPoints.getDropDownHeaders}${element}`;

        cosnt {data} = await axios.post(url,request);
        newState.data[element] = data;
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
    return newState;
};
```

Comment: async callback to forEach would not work as expected. that's why you use for...in loop